# Property of markers not found of object type of GMSMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

After updating google maps framework. I m facing with the following issue.

```
Property of markers not found of object type of GMSMapView
```

I have just replace the framework with the latest framework. I have also tried to remove and add new framework. But nothing working.

Comment: Have you check if the **Framework Search Path** under Built Settings to verify that the app is linking to the latest framework version? Make sure that only the latest version path is there.

Comment: Framework Search Path will be the same as previous? i dint have changed

Comment: If you have the latest framework, the version of the framework should be different and the path should be different. Eg: change from GoogleMaps-iOS-1.8.0 to GoogleMaps-iOS-1.8.1. Show me the code related to markers.